# Apache Camel aggregate messages within timeframe

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any way to aggregate messages within time frame in Apache Camel.
I want to calcuate instant TPS of my system by pushing a messages into it and consuming from other side.
On the consumer side i want make an aggregator which aggregates messages passed within some time frame (lets say 1 second) and provides some calcualtions.

So far i can see Camel provides inactivity timeout handling for aggregation triggering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

see [Camel's aggregator EIP](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) for exactly this...

```
from("direct:start")
    .aggregate(constant(true), new MyAggregationStrategy()).completionInterval(1000)
        .to("mock:aggregated");
```